# Google Actions: Stop sending updates from "app_name" issue

Tags: actions-on-google

I followed these steps to stop Google Actions sending updates for my action: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/overview

When I send "stop sending updates from my home finder", Google Assistant shows me a list of active notifications in a carousel.

[Google Assistant Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFMfP.jpg)

Pushing one of the carousel items doesn't seem to trigger any kind of event/action. I tried to continue the conversation by sending:
- "first"
- "9am"
- "stop sending updates from my home finder at 9am"

But none of the options seems to cancel the update(s). As a result of my testing, I have several updates popping up my screen during the day, which is pretty annoying :-)

[Google Assistant Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA04t.jpg)

I'm using Google Assistant on iOS.

I've already posted this issue on the Google Actions Product Forum, with no result. Can someone help me out?

Kind regards,
Philip

Comment: Have you published this app, or is it still a test draft?

Comment: It's still in draft

Comment: Issue solved in latest Google Assistant App release. Please note you should uninstall and reinstall the app to get it fixed.